# Firefox Add-on localization - How to force a language?

Tags: firefox, localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox Add-on using the Add-on SDK with jpm.

I'd like to use the built-in `l10n` functionality to automatically handle localization, **except** for when a user specifically overrides the language (f.i. by selecting the language from a drop-down menu).

Another use-case is to have the add-on fall back to a specific default language when none of the user's preferred languages are available.
Currently it just falls back to the l10n identifier, as described in the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/l10n).

Is there a way to force the `l10n` module to use a specific `locale\*.properties` file?

Comment: Cool question, I dont know how to disobey the users language setting just in your addon, Im interested to see answer. I know i can change the pref `general.useragent.locale` but that will change l10n in everything, not just your own language (somethings will need a browser restart to update the l10n if you change that pref, like addon manager)